# How to solve permission handler error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-permissions, android-handler

Not sure where I made mistake but I got error while implementing permission_handler: ^7.1.0 ,the error message is  ``` C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\http://pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-7.2.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\ServiceManager.java:152: warning: [deprecation] getDefaultAdapter() in BluetoothAdapter has been deprecated
final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 ```
Below I attached necessary screenshots [image: flutter doctor -v]
And I also given permission in Androidmanifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

And compileSdkVersion 31, minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 30. Hope I have given all necessary details. If anything need please comment and please help to solve this issue and I don’t want to change my sdk version. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try flutter clean, delete the pubspec.lock file. Then run flutter pub get and then flutter run. It should resolve the issue.

Comment: No @kaushik still getting same error

Comment: In pubspec.yaml file give `permission_handler:any` and try once please

Comment: Iam getting same error dude @kaushik

Comment: Paste the full error here.

Comment: After permission_handler: any and doing flutter clean , delete the pubspec.lock file. Then run flutter pub get and then flutter run , it working fine without any error.but how can I know which version it is using because we gave it as “any”?

Comment: Run flutter pub outdated. It will list all packages and it's versions too

Comment: Hey @Kaushik I posed another question can you please go through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999701/how-to-customize-the-checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-rang-slider-in-flutters). Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the compileSdkVersion to 30 or 31 in android\app\build.gradle can fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

after try lot of solution this one solve my issue

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
```

//            useProguard true
multiDexEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}

Answer (score -1):

in pubspec.yaml Change permission_handler TO
permission_handler: ^8.1.5