# How to customize the checkboxes, radio buttons and Rang slider in Flutters?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-radiobutton

Hello Folks I am playing with Buttons to customize the buttons but I didn't find a way to approach the expected design. basically, I wanted to customize the **1)** Multiple checkBoxes with Grey color Background and Black color Check Mark **2)** RangeSlider Inactive bar with Grey color **3)** Radio Button with black Color and I Want to unselect all, I understand that in Radio Button user cant Unselect all the buttons but I Want to unselect all with or without Radio Buttons(any different way is also fine) **4)** same as 3rd point but Square Box with Grey color Background and Black color Check Mark. I attached a screenshot of my code and Expected design and also pasted my code. Please guys Help me to approach Expected Design, Please feel free to do comments for any clarity. Thanks in Advance.
What I want My expected Design[image: My Design] My Result UI[image: My resulted UI]
**Main File**

```
import 'package:filters2/filter_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Dialog',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Filters'),
      ),
      body:  Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: (){
            filterBottomSheet();
          },
          color: Colors.green,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
          child: Text('Filters',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.white),),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  filterBottomSheet(){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        isDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return Filters();
        }
    );
  }
}
```

**Filters Class**

```
import 'package:filters2/Fruit_model_class.dart';
import 'package:filters2/color_model_class.dart';
import 'package:filters2/mobile_model_class.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Filters extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _FiltersState createState() => _FiltersState();
}

class _FiltersState extends State<Filters> {

/*--------MobileList-multiple checklist-------*/
  List<MobileList> availableMobiles = [
    MobileList(id: 0, companyName: "Google", model: "Pixel 6 Pro"),
    MobileList(id: 1, companyName: "Apple", model: "Iphone Xr"),
    MobileList(id: 2, companyName: "Xiaomi", model: "Redmi note 10"),
  ];
  List<MobileList> selectedMobiles = [];
  /*------Price Range Selection-RangeSlider--------*/
  RangeValues _currentRangeValues = const RangeValues(40000, 80000);
  int minPrice = 20000;
  int maxPrice = 90000;
  /*Radio--fruits*/
  String radioItem1 = 'Mango';
  int fruitGroupId = 0;
  List<FruitsList> fList = [
    FruitsList(id: 0, name: "Mango",),
    FruitsList(id: 1, name: "Apple",),
    FruitsList(id: 2, name: "Banana",),
    FruitsList(id: 3, name: "Cherry",),
  ];
  /*Radio--Colors*/
  String radioItem2 = 'Red';
  int? colorGroupId ;
  List<ColorsList> cList = [
    ColorsList(id: 0, name: "Blue",),
    ColorsList(id: 1, name: "Red",),
    ColorsList(id: 2, name: "Green",),
    ColorsList(id: 3, name: "Yellow",),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //olor: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            topRight: Radius.circular(10),
          )
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Container(
              child: Text("Filter",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Container(
              child: Text("Select Mobiles (multiple selection)",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Divider(),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex:1,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: availableMobiles.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, playerIndex){
                          return CheckboxListTile(
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              title:Text(availableMobiles[playerIndex].companyName),
                              value: selectedMobiles.contains(availableMobiles[playerIndex]),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                if(selectedMobiles.contains(availableMobiles[playerIndex])){
                                  selectedMobiles.remove(availableMobiles[playerIndex]);
                                }
                                else {
                                  selectedMobiles.add(availableMobiles[playerIndex]);
                                }
                                setState(() {

                                });
                              }
                          );
                        }
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child:Container(
                        color: Colors.white ,
                      ) ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Divider(),
            Container(
              child: Text("Year",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Divider(),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text("20000",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RangeSlider(
                      values: _currentRangeValues,
                      min: minPrice.toDouble(),
                      max: maxPrice.toDouble(),
                      divisions: maxPrice - minPrice,
                      activeColor: Colors.black,
                      labels: RangeLabels(
                        _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
                        _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentRangeValues = values;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text("90000",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20))),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Divider(),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("Fruits (Single selection)",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                        Column(
                          children:
                          fList.map((data) => RadioListTile(
                            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            title: Text("${data.name}"),
                            groupValue: fruitGroupId,
                            value: data.id,
                            onChanged: (val){
                              setState(() {
                                radioItem1 = data.name;
                                fruitGroupId = data.id;
                              });
                            },
                          )).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      flex:2,
                      child: Container(
                        //width: 5,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("Colors",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                        Column(
                          children:
                          cList.map((colorData) => RadioListTile(
                            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            title: Text("${colorData.name}"),
                            groupValue: colorGroupId,
                            value: colorData.id,
                            onChanged: (val){
                              setState(() {
                                radioItem2 = colorData.name;
                                colorGroupId = colorData.id;
                              });
                            },
                          )).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child:Container(
                        color: Colors.white ,
                      ) ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**mobile_model_class**

```
class MobileList {
  int id;
  String companyName;
  String model;

  MobileList({required this.id, required this.companyName, required this.model});
}
```

**Fruit_model_class**

```
class MobileList {
  int id;
  String companyName;
  String model;

  MobileList({required this.id, required this.companyName, required this.model});
}
```

**color_model_class**

```
class ColorsList {
  String name;
  int id;
  ColorsList({required this.name,required this.id});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change color of checkbox you can use

```
   Checkbox(
      value: isCheck,
      checkColor: Colors.black,  // change color here
      activeColor: Colors.grey,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          isCheck = value;
        });
      }),
```

To change color of radio button try

```
     Theme(
              data: ThemeData(
                //Change color here
                unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                       Radio(), 
                       Radio()
                ],
              ),
            );
```

Comment: Thanks, @kaushik, can you explain how to decrease space between tiles, I used `contentPadding: Edgeinserts.all(0)` for both ListView.builder and CheckboxListTile even though space is not decreased.

Comment: Wrap the checkbox with a sizedbox and add a sizedbox between checkbox and title

Comment: Hey @Kaushik  , I had posted another question related to flutter camera can you please help me [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70412440/flutter-image-is-not-capturing-ontap-button-unless-doing-hot-reload?noredirect=1#comment124469642_70412440)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SliderTheme` class to customize your slider color and shape.

```
    SliderTheme(
        data: SliderThemeData(
                this.trackHeight,
                activeTrackColor:Colors.grey,
                inactiveTrackColor:Colors.black,
                thumbColor: Colors.green,
                thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 20)),
        child: Slider(
              value: _value,
              onChanged: (val) {
                _value = val;
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Hope the answer is helpful to you.